# Count content views in Php, Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi, I am creating a simple news website and I need to count news views. Currently I have 25000 rows and 25 columns. The hits count increases per page reload like Joomla. How should I structure the tables?
I have 2 approaches to this issue:

1. Create column named `hits` in the content table.
2. Create a new table that has 2 columns: `content_id` and `hits`.

I used the first approach and I think that slows my site.Will the second approaches perform better than the first one? Is there a better approach?

Comment: option 1 sounds the best. Option 2 would be redundant

Comment: I don't think this query alone is slowing down your site. I think you should 1. check your code for redundant queries and 2. check your content tables (i.e the content_id should be an AUTO_INCREMENTing PRIMARY INDEX).

Comment: In option 2: i thought updating 2 columned table is faster than update 25 columned table :). Is that wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know what's your logic in MySQL or PHP or what is you current table structure for news but I would suggest you to use **Stored Procedure** in MySQL as

```
Begin
   update tblnews set hits = hits+1;
   select news from tblnews;
End
```

and off course use **PHP PDO Prepared Statement** for performance

and if you are trying to get last 10 news or something like that then must set **Indexing** for content_id say like Primary key with auto_increment for better retrieval of query otherwise don't even use content_id column. I don't think there should be any hard structre for table. This would definitely increase performance and more than 100000000 rows would not make any big difference I hope. I don't think there would be any other better solution because these 2 queries needs to be performed at every page view.

Answer (score 0):

Option  1 sounds the best. Option 2 is redundant because your just storing the hits. Again you would a join query to pull the hits